# Match everything until the whole regex matches again

Tags: python, regex

This is the string I'm trying to match on (real one is much longer).

```
VC1000 Venture Capital 4 cr.
This is a class about venture capital
and more description, that could mention a future course like
VC2000 but might not
VC2000 venture capital II 4 cr.
Another description about blah
VC 3000 venture capital III 4-6 cr.
back again
```

I'm trying to get groups that would look like

- `[VC1000]`
- `[Venture Capital]`
- `[4]`
- `[This is a class about venture capital and more description, that could mention a future course like VC2000 but might not]`

I almost got it but I'm not sure how to get the description between class listings. Right now I have:

`(^\*?[A-Z]{2}\s?[0-9]{4}) (.*?)([0-9]|[0-9]-[0-9]+)\s?cr\.`

But i'm not sure how to proceed. Adding `.*` matches too much, and doing `.*` with the first group from above prevents the first group getting caught every other match.

What's the trick I'm missing?

Comment: Do the course lines always end in `cr.`?

Comment: Try enclosing your regex between start string `^` and end string `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I4PKGo/1)):

```py
import re

pat = r'^([A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4})\s+([^\n]+?)(\d+-?\d*\s+cr\.)$(.*?)(?=^[A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4}\s+[^\n]+?\d+-?\d*\s+cr\.$|\Z)'
pat = re.compile(pat, flags=re.S|re.M)

text = '''\
VC1000 Venture Capital 4 cr.
This is a class about venture capital
and more description, that could mention a future course like
VC2000 but might not
VC2000 venture capital II 4 cr.
Another description about blah
VC 3000 venture capital III 4-6 cr.
back again'''

for a, b, c, d in pat.findall(text):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
VC1000
Venture Capital 
4 cr.

This is a class about venture capital
and more description, that could mention a future course like
VC2000 but might not

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VC2000
venture capital II 
4 cr.

Another description about blah

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VC 3000
venture capital III 
4-6 cr.

back again
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Was just writing up pretty much exactly the same regex...